# How to tell if soundmanager2 is using html5?

Tags: javascript, html, soundmanager2

[soundmanager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/) will use html5 audio instead of flash if various properties are set and it thinks conditions are Ok.

Once soundmanager2 has decided, is there a property on the SoundManager object that will tell me whether it went for html5 or flash?

(I know it mentions it in the debug log but I'm looking for a property I could query)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's documented but the `SMSound` object has an `isHTML5` property that you can check to see if a given sound is using HTML5 Audio.

The `SoundManager` object also has an `html5` property that contains information about what audio formats are supported by the current browser.

Answer (score 3):

set this on soundManager.setup()

```
soundManager.setup({
    useHTML5Audio: true,
    preferFlash: false
});
```

Comment: That tells soundmanager to use HTML5 if it can. But that doesn't mean it will (depends on client). What I'm asking is: How do I tell if it really is using HTML5 or not?

Comment: ok, You have to use the method isHtml5 of Sound object, that indicates if is using HTML5 Audio for playback

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways:

1. Check the version property of your SoundManager2 instance:

   ```
   > soundManager.version
   "V2.97a.20131201 (AS3/Flash 9)" // Flash version
   "V2.97a.20131201 (HTML5-only mode)" // HTML5 version
   ```
2. Check boolean:

   ```
   > soundManager.html5.usingFlash
   ```